# Basic set intersection question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A_{1}, A_{2}, ...A_{k}, ...$ be a collection of sets(possibly uncountably many). Is is true that

$\bigcap_{k} A_{k}$ $\bigcap  B$ $= \bigcap_{k} (A_{k}\bigcap B)$. Where B is some generic set? I'm doing an analysis problem and the verification of this identity would make the solution of my problem very easy. But I'm not sure if this identity holds for uncountably many sets.

Comment: It holds for any family of sets. Something is in the lefthand set iff it belongs to $B$ and to each $A_k$, which is true iff it belongs to each $A_k\cap B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you

Comment: My pleasure.$\;$

Comment: Yes they're equal, because "and $x\in B$" has the same truth value when it's said once (on the lefthand side) as when it's said possibly uncountably many times, for each $k$. You probably should require that the $A_k$ are a _nonempty_ collection of sets. If the intersection of the empty family is treated as undefined, then the two sides are both undefined and trivially equal. However, if all the $A_k$ and $B$ are subsets of some "universe" set $U$, and if the intersection of the empty family is $U$ by convention, then the lefthand side equals $B$ but the righthand side equals $U$.